# IllegalArgumentException which prevents me to start tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, servlets

I'm working on a dynamic web application and http-servlets in Eclipse with tomcat 7.0 server. The server did not start suddenly, and still returns following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [core.Flowpost_h1_h3] and [core.Flowpost_h2_h1] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/Flowpost] which is not permitted
```

I can see that both of my http servlet classes "Flowpost_h1_h3" and "Flowpost_h2_h1" has:

```
@WebServlet("/Flowpost")
public class Flowpost_h2_h1 extends HttpServlet {
```

and

```
@WebServlet("/Flowpost")
public class Flowpost_h1_h3 extends HttpServlet {
```

even though I'm changing the "/Flowpost" in one of the classes, it still returns exactly the same error. What do I need to modify in my project to get rid of this issue ?.

my web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>printinfo_rest</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>PrintInfo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>core.PrintInfo</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PrintInfo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check if you also have a `web.xml` with Servlet mappings (they would overwrite hardcoded ones):

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/path</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I have, I have added my web.xml as well

Comment: The servlet in question is not defined in web.xml (therefore this is not causing your issue). Also try to undeploy, restart and deploy.

Comment: I have saved my project, removed the virtual machine with Eclipse, and reintalled it, but the error repeats